# Putting all desktop items into a new folder

Tags: python, performance, beginner, object-oriented, file-system

I'm quite a newbie with Python, but I wanted to try my own little project, so I made a small script that puts all the desktop icons/folders into a newly created folder (called "Desktop1") if there are more than 25 items on the desktop.

```
import os
import shutil

#My user on windows is Shadow so you're not like 'huh??'

os.chdir("C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop")
desktop = os.listdir("C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop")
desktopFiles = []

#Folder that the desktop files/icons will move to once created
newFolder = "C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop\Desktop1" 

#Function that does the moving
def moveFilesToFolder(files, directory, folder): 
    for files in directory:
        shutil.move(files, folder)

#Place the files into a list so I can determine how many there are
for x in desktop:                       
    desktopFiles.append(x)

if len(desktopFiles) > 25:    #If there's more than 25 files/icons on the desktop

   #If you already have an EMPTY folder named Desktop1 on your Desktop 
    if os.path.exists(newFolder) and os.listdir(newFolder) == []: 
        moveFilesToFolder(file, desktop, newFolder)  
        print "Desktop1 already exists and is empty, so the files have been placed there"


    else:                 #Otherwise, make Desktop1 and move the icons/files into it
        os.mkdir(newFolder)
        moveFilesToFolder(file, desktop, newFolder)
```

What can I do to make it better? It works well and gets the job done, but is there any improvement I can make to it now (performance, syntax, etc.) that I can use for any later programs I may want to create? I feel like I'm not using object oriented programming at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hard-coded `"C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop"` three times.  Once would have been too many, as it turns a general-purpose script into a throwaway script.  Your script could take a command-line parameter or [infer the desktop directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000638/1157100) for the current user.

If you must hard-code a path as a [string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000638/1157100), use raw strings to prevent Python from interpreting special backslash escape sequences such as `\n` for <kbd>Newline</kbd>.

---

Let's focus on this function:

> ```
> #Function that does the moving
> def moveFilesToFolder(files, directory, folder): 
>     for files in directory:
>         shutil.move(files, folder)
> ```

1. What is `files`?  It's a parameter that you accept but never use.  Rather, you reuse the same variable name as a dummy variable for iteration.
2. Using an iteration variable with a plural name is awkward.
3. What do the parameters `directory` and `folder` mean?  How about renaming `directory` → `files` and `folder` → `dest_dir` for clarity?

I was curious how you actually call that function, given the weird parameter design.

> ```
> moveFilesToFolder(file, desktop, newFolder)
> ```

At first glance, it appears that the script should fail, since `file` is never defined as a variable in your script.  However, it turns out that [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is the name of a built-in constructor function.  So, you're passing some arbitrary function as a parameter to a function that ends up doing nothing with it.  I find that rather funny.

Comment: Thank you for this! I used your suggestions and made a lot of changes to the code and its much clearer/more general-purpose oriented

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see:

- Put moveFilesToFolder to the top of the file ( but below the imports ).
- Check the length of desktop, and if it is less than 25, quit.  This would be done before appending to desktopFiles
- Does desktopFiles even need to exist?
- Both branches of the if/else statement move the files, so they can be brought to after that statement

Some added features I can think of:

- Make the target directory a command line argument so I can say where the files get moved to.
- Add an option for if the program should create the directory if it doesn't .exist
- and an option to be safe and not overwrite existing files.